How to Launch a Windows Application Before the Desktop Loads and Then Show the Desktop After the Application Starts"
I am developing a Windows application that needs to be launched before the desktop environment appears (i.e., before the user sees the desktop). Once the application starts, I want the desktop to load and become visible, while still keeping the application running. The application should be visible first, and only after it starts, the desktop environment should show up. How can I achieve this behavior?
I added my application to the Windows startup, but it doesn't launch before the desktop loads, as I intended. I want the application to start first, before the desktop appears, and only after the application starts, the desktop should load. How can I make it work as expected?

"I want the application to start first, before the desktop appears" - why? Are you creating a kiosk-like system, or something like that?

I want to prevent unauthorized users from using the computer without using kiosk mode. Only my application will run, and I will switch to the desktop when I want. Users are bypassing this by using the Windows key and virtual desktops to send the application to the background, so I’m looking for a solution to prevent this as well.

You could replace the default Shell app with your app.

Set your programs to start at login through the task scheduler.

The Explorer startup sequence has a number of phases, carefully
arranged to get visible things ready first, and less visible things
ready later. And one of the lowest priority items is the Startup
group.

Other references you should read:
Performance gains at the cost of other components
Startup apps start up when I tell them
Starting up inside the box
